# Which framework is used for React Native? or Which is better Redux or Redux saga?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Which framework should I follow to create react-native-based apps or what is the most appropriate way if I want to use Redux for creating new apps?
I just want to build an app using react native along with Redux and I am not sure what library should I use for that.
I know little about Redux Thunk and Saga but as a newbie I am confused about what could be used for the app that gives me more flexibility.

Comment: Are you asking about additional libraries to extend react native development or possibly some development tools? You might want to update your question to be more specific so we can give you better answers :)

Answer (score 1):

From my personal expirience, to develop I use [Atom](https://atom.io/) once installed you can add more plugins in order to customize it.

For debug purposes I use a couple of Chrome plugins like [React Developers Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) and [Redux Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=es)

As I said, these are my options but there are so many others...